# Is it possible to simulate string.match with a regexp.exec loop when the regexp matches the empty string?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, match

It is common knowledge that the exec method from RegExps can get used to find all matches in a string. However, I just found out that if the regexp matches the empty string this loop can get stuck forever

```
var s = '1234'
var r = /()/g;
var m;
var i = 0;
while( (m = r.exec(s)) ){
   console.log(i, m[0]);
   if(++i >= 50){ console.log("infinite loop!"); break }
}
```

What is really weird though is that the plain string.match methods does not get stuck:

```
'1234'.match(/()/g) // Gives ["", "", "", "", "", ""]
```

I wonder how the match method is defined to work differently from the exec loop. So far the only way I found to avoid getting stuck like the match method does involves abusing the string.replace method, in a horrid hack:

```
var matches = [];
'1234'.replace(/()/g, function(m){ matches.push(m) });
```

**So my question is:**

How do the match and replace return a finite results when the regexp matches the empty string? Can I use the same technique to avoid getting stuck in the exec loop?

Comment: Why are you trying to match a useless pattern like that?

Comment: @Pointy: It could be user input... or maybe there's some valid reason to match, for example, `/[a-z]*/` as opposed to `/[a-z]+/`... I'm not really sure.

Comment: @Pointy: This came up for a function of mine that dynamically builds a regex that is the alternation of a bunch of sugregexes. During testing, I realized that I had no idea what to do in this particular corner case. And minitech is right - it ultimately boils down to user input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One (icky) solution is to make sure it's not in the same place as last time:

```
var s = '1234'
var r = /()/g;
var m;
var i = 0;
var lastPosition = -1;

while(m = r.exec(s)) {
    if(m.index === lastPosition) {
        r.lastIndex++;
        continue;
    }

    lastPosition = m.index;

    console.log(i, m[0]);
}
```

Comment: Is this documented somewhere in the String.match specification though? I worry that an ad-hoc hack like this will not necessarily have the same behaviour in all cases...

Comment: @missingno: In `String.match`? No, I don't know about the specifics of `String.match`.

Comment: @missingno: If you mean `index`, yes, that's documented and should work. About incrementing `lastIndex`, I'll have to check.

Comment: I did some more searching and it turns out that this is precisely how its done behind the scenes as well. See step 8.iii [here](http://es5.github.com/#x15.5.4.10)

Comment: Wow, lucky guess :D And I've checked, and it *appears* to have no compatibility issues either - who'd have thought?